# Динамические модели в Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

Задача такая: в зависимости от определённых условий, скажем енв значения, нужно использовать разные модели пользователей, точнее у них будут отличны поля. Причем обращения по коду желательно сделать к одному классу, например User. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Раз у Вас несколько моделей пользователь, то должно быть и несколько таблиц с пользователями, со своими полями для каждого. Далее я бы сделал `Facade` тем самым обеспечив единую точку входа для получения модели пользователя!

После регистрации фасада в сервис провайдере, в любом файле где получаете поля из модели пользователя, нужно вызывать что-то типо: `UserFacade::getModel();` из фасада нужно вернуть `$this->model`, предварительно присвоив необходимую модель

Сам объект возвращаемый фасадом:

```
...
protected $model;
public function __construct() {
    //Лучше не env() а создать config файл!!! и в нем получать из env()
    switch(env("USER_MODEL")) {
        case "a":
            $this->model = \App\User::class;
            break;
        case "b":
            $this->model = \App\User2::class;
            break;
        case "c":
            $this->model = \App\User3::class;
            break;
        //case ....
        default: 
            $this->model = \App\User::class;
            break;
    }
}

public function getModel() {
    return $this->model;
}
...
```

Думаю суть ясна. Ну это как один из вариантов! Как правило можно придумать и другие решения, главное фантазия! Данный пример как идея!